# loading trie from Sqlite

Tags: objective-c

I am working on a iOS custom keyboard. for the autocorrect I am using Trie with my own word scoring logic. Every time the keyboard pops up, in viewdidLoad I load NSArray from SQLite database which takes .01ms. But my concern is when loading the trie which is taking .8ms. Instead of loading the trie every time, is there a way I can load it only once and trie should be always ready when the keyboard pops up?

Comment: Just like userdefaults it has to be permanently stored